# Issue with Android XML layout

Tags: android

Why is my layout, shown below, containing `EditText` and `Button`, not shown? The `MapView` is taking up the entire view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        a:layout_width="fill_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            a:layout_width="fill_parent"
            a:layout_height="40dip"
            a:background="#50ffffff"
            a:orientation="horizontal"
            a:paddingBottom="0dip"
            a:paddingLeft="5dip"
            a:paddingRight="5dip"
            a:paddingTop="5dip" >

            <Button
                a:id="@+id/smsCancelButton"
                a:layout_width="70dip"
                a:layout_height="40dip"
                a:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                a:layout_weight="1.0"
                a:enabled="false"
                a:text="@string/sms_cancel_abbr" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="not shown"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        a:paddingLeft="10dip"
        a:paddingRight="10dip"
        a:paddingTop="30dip"
        android:max="100" >
    </SeekBar>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- #dcdcdc -->

<LinearLayout
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    a:background="#dcdcdc"
    a:orientation="horizontal"
    a:paddingBottom="5dip"
    a:paddingLeft="5dip"
    a:paddingRight="5dip"
    a:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <EditText
        a:id="@+id/smsBody"
        a:layout_width="0dip"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_weight="1.0"
        a:autoText="true"
        a:capitalize="sentences"
        a:hint="@string/sms_enter_message"
        a:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
        a:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        a:maxLines="10"
        a:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_button" />

    <LinearLayout
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            a:id="@+id/smsSendButton"
            a:layout_width="wrap_content"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            a:layout_weight="1.0"
            a:enabled="false"
            a:nextFocusLeft="@+id/smsBody"
            a:text="@string/sms_send_abbr" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You probably want to set the layout_height of the MapView to 0dp, and the layout_weight to 1.

Comment: Have you ever consider to rebuild your layout structure? There are only have 5 Views and you're making complicated a simple thing. I recommend you to build your layout with one Relative Layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topmost `LinearLayout` doesn't explicitly set an orientation.  `LinearLayout` defaults to `horizontal` orientation if you don't specify one.  So the first pane containing the map, whose width is set to `fill_parent`, fills the entire screen and the second pane, containing the `EditText` and `Button`, is cut off the right-hand side of the screen.

You need to be aware that setting any child inside a `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` will eat up all the space remaining, so that any children following will not show.  For instance, say you have a vertical LL, and four children: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.  Height on `a` is set to `wrap_content`, and is only maybe 10 or 20dp high.  `b` has height set to `fill_parent`, `c` and `d` both have height set to `wrap_content`.  In this example, `b` will fill the entirety of the screen that isn't taken up by a, and `c` and `d` will never show.  It's a frustrating limitation of `LinearLayout` that you can partially, but not completely, workaround using weights.